.cshrc setting LANG=C prevents Fedora 39 gnome terminal from opening a window?
I just installed Fedora 39 and installed tcsh.   After chsh I can reboot, and clicking the terminal launch icon, I get a terminal window immediately, running tcsh.  Good.
Now I install my old .cshrc file into my home directory, and reboot.  After re-logging in, clicking the terminal launch icon, I get a spinning cursor for a couple minutes.
Selectively commenting out portions of the .cshrc to see what the issue is, I see it is a command setenv LANG C.  If I comment this out and reboot, terminal launch produces the expected terminal, with tcsh and with the full .cshrc contents having been applied.  If I then uncomment this line and re-login, then back to the spinning cursor.
With setenv LANG C not commented out, I can login with Putty 0.78 with success.  tcsh runs with LANG C as expected.
So: what is preventing the gnome terminal program from even opening a window if cshrc specifies an unsupported LANG?

What's the exit code from the setenv LANG C command?

setenv is a shell built-in so wouldn't have an exit code, right?  And under what circumstances could setenv fail?  If you mean the gnome-terminal I'm not sure how to check: how can I run it if I can't open a terminal, I wonder?

Maybe LANG set to C is making something in .cshrc hang? What happens if you move setenv LANG C to the end of .cshrc?

Can you run tcsh from within you're already running terminal after you've uncommented that setenv line?

builtins have exit codes just the same. But a failing builtin doesn't necessarily exit the shell. For instance, setenv @ returns a 1 exit status but does not exit the shell unless tcsh was started as tcsh -e

How can setenv cause a problem?  The rest of the cshrc isn't running other commands, merely setting aliases and environment variables and so on.  And if I ssh via PuTTY from my Windows box the cshrc runs fine.

gnome-terminal needs a UTF-8 locale to start up. I'm not sure why exactly. Anyway, independently from this, really no one should use a non-UTF-8 locale by default. Try C.UTF-8 or en_US.UTF-8. Revert to C for individual apps only which really need this for whatever obscure reason. If you really don't want to touch LANG then try to set only LC_CTYPE to a UTF-8 one.
